# set source2 globally in SAS

Tags: sas

Looking at [this](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000214504.htm), I am wondering how I can set source2 globally to apply for all include statements. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `options source2;` to the autoexec file

Comment: sorry about my ignorance, but what is an autoexec file? I have a 'driver program' which contains all the include statements. i guess that's the same?

Comment: It's the program that SAS runs when started.  You can see where it is by right clicking the SAS icon, selecting properties and looking in the target. The autoexec file path follows -autoexec.  However, if you have a driver program then you can add the option to that instead and it will work for all subsequent %includes.  You don't need to add / source2 after each one

Comment: Thanks. yes i have a driver program. Currently use: Options compress = yes, source2; but get error. Any ideas?

Comment: Take out the comma after `compress=yes`

Comment: Or add it to the config.ini.